# Table formatting issue Chrome vs IE/FireFox

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, html-table

Can anyone tell me why this table looks perfect in Chrome but not in IE or FireFox?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="padding-left:6px;"><img src="http://www.purelycustom.com/name_decals/style2/borders/tl_black_blue.png" /></td>
            <td colspan="4" style="height:15px; background-color:#00F"></td>
            <td rowspan="4"><img src="http://www.purelycustom.com/name_decals/style2/borders/right_black_blue.png" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" height="13px" style="background-color:#000"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><img src="http://www.purelycustom.com/name_decals/style2/borders/l_black.png" /></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#000000"><img src="http://www.purelycustom.com/name_decals/style2/flags/flag.png" /></td>
            <td style="background-color:#000000"><span style="color:#FFFFFF">YOUR</span></td>
            <td style="background-color:#000000" width="15px"></td>
            <td style="background-color:#000000"><span style="color:#FFFFFF">NAME</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#000000" colspan="5"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I included the !DOCTYPE declaration because I know that that has an affect on how the table gets displayed.

Comment: What does 'perfect' mean. (So we can attempt to decipher what is imperfect about IE/Fx.)

Comment: If you look at it in a browser, you will see. In Chrome it looks like one complete image. In IE and FireFox, there are two white spaces that break it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the width of the 1st `td` in your `tr`'s... if you add `align="right"` to the `td` the images will line up.. may override when adding specific widths to `tds`

something more effective would be a `div` with a background image instead of messing with table alignment..

Comment: I added align="right" to both td's that were giving me a problem and it fixed the formatting issue. Thanks.